# Google Cloud Platform: make a script to record the results of VM monitoring in csv

Tags: bash, google-cloud-platform, cloud, virtual-machine, google-cloud-shell

I got the task to make a list of all CPU, memory, and Disk monitoring of all vm in a project in the last 5 minutes. Previously I did it manually. Then I want to make it automatic with a script. Previously I had made a GCP list service script (VM, SQL, Redis, Cloud run), but it was limited to a list of names, ip, amount of memory, and memory type. and the script worked.
But for monitoring it's a bit different, I've made the following code but it's still an error, can anyone help me?

The code:

```
#!/bin/bash
# specify the output file
if [ -z $1 ]; then
  echo "Please Run like..."
  echo "./script.sh project_id"
  exit
fi
output_file="vm_monitoring_list.csv"
input_file="vm_monitoring_temp.txt"

if [ -f "$input_file" ]; then
    rm $input_file
fi

if [ -f "$output_file" ]; then
    rm $output_file
fi

touch $output_file
touch $input_file
echo "Name,CPU,Memory,Disk" >> $output_file
gcloud compute instances list --project $1 --format="value(name)" --sort-by=name> $input_file

cpu_metric="compute.googleapis.com/instance/cpu/utilization"
mem_metric="compute.googleapis.com/instance/memory/usage"
disk_metric="compute.googleapis.com/instance/disk/bytes_used"

start_time=$(date -u -d "-5 minutes" +%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ)
end_time=$(date -u +%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ)

cpu_result=$(gcloud monitoring dashboards --project=$1 --filter="resource.type=global AND resource.label.instance_name=$compute_name" --start-time=$start_time --end-time=$end_time --format="value(point.value.doubleValue)" --aggregator=mean)



 loop through each line in the input file
while read compute_name; do
 start_time=$(date -u -d "-5 minutes" +%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ)
 end_time=$(date -u +%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ)

  cpu_result=$(gcloud monitoring dashboards read $cpu_metric --project=$1 --filter="resource.type=global AND resource.label.instance_name=$compute_name" --start-time=$start_time --end-time=$end_time --format="value(point.value.doubleValue)" --aggregator=mean)
  mem_result=$(gcloud monitoring read $mem_metric --project=$1 --filter="resource.type=global AND resource.label.instance_name=$compute_name" --start-time=$start_time --end-time=$end_time --format="value(point.value.doubleValue)" --aggregator=mean)
  disk_result=$(gcloud monitoring read $disk_metric --project=$1 --filter="resource.type=global AND resource.label.instance_name=$compute_name" --start-time=$start_time --end-time=$end_time --format="value(point.value.doubleValue)" --aggregator=mean)


  echo "$compute_name,$cpu_result,$mem_result,$disk_result" >> $output_file
  echo "In Progress $compute_name"
done < $input_file

rm $input_file
echo "Progress Done ... "
echo ""
echo ""
echo -e "\033[5mNB::PLEASE MAKE SURE YOU'RE ALREADY DOWNLOAD output.csv BEFORE RUNNING AGAIN\033[0m"
```

Note: The script runs with cloud shell

Help the troubleshooting code

Comment: Have you tried pasting your script at https://shellcheck.net ?

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I've tried it but shellcheck only checks from the side of the code framework. but it looks like this problem is from the google service command

Comment: What error are you getting?